# I can't avois this select N+1

Tags: nhibernate, select-n-plus-1

I have this mapping ( it comes from adventureworks since I used it in a demo app for an automatic paging collection )

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper(new SimpleModelInspector());

            mapper.Class<Contact>(
                k => { 
                    k.Id(i => i.ContactID, m => m.Generator(Generators.Native));
                    k.Schema("Person");
                } 
                );
            mapper.Class<Employee>(
                k => 
                {
                    k.Id(i => i.EmployeeID, m => m.Generator(Generators.Native));
                    k.Schema("HumanResources");
                    k.ManyToOne(c => c.Contact, m =>  m.Column("ContactID"));
                }
                );
            mapper.Class<SalesOrderHeader>(
                k =>
                {
                    k.Id(i => i.SalesOrderID,m=>m.Generator(Generators.Native));
                    k.Schema("Sales");
                    k.ManyToOne(c => c.SalesPerson, m => m.Column("SalesPersonID"));
                    k.ManyToOne(c => c.Contact, m => m.Column("ContactID"));
                }
                );

            var map = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
            cfg.AddDeserializedMapping(map,string.Empty);
```

and the following ( limited ) query:

```
var list = NHHelper.Instance.CurrentSession.Query<SalesOrderHeader>()
                            .Fetch(k => k.Contact)
                            .Fetch(k => k.SalesPerson)
                            .Skip(first)
                            .Take(count)
                            .ToList();
```

I can't remove the select N+1 caused by employee-contact, how can I do ?
Consider mapping too can be changed !

**`EDIT`: I add the working solution by @cremor**

```
 var list = NHHelper.Instance.CurrentSession.Query<SalesOrderHeader>()
                            .Fetch(k => k.Contact)
                            .Fetch(k => k.SalesPerson).ThenFetch(k=>k.Contact)
                            .Skip(first)
                            .Take(count)
                            .ToList();
```

this will avoid the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `.ThenFetch(c => c.Contact)` after `.Fetch(k => k.SalesPerson)` should also fetch the `Contact` of the `Employee`.